# Add player score to social framework message in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, social-framework

I'm making a SpriteKit based-app, and I have a spriteNode that shares to facebook when I tap it. This is the code that runs when it is tapped:

```
func shareToFacebook(){
    var shareToFacebook: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    shareToFacebook.setInitialText("I just got x points in ....")
    shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "AppLogo87.png"))
    let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
    vc.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I also have a score system set up within the game. What I want to do is display the score in the setInitialText message. I want it to say "I just got ___ points in app". I can't figure out how to add the player's score to the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this twice and feel like I'm missing something, however if you are really just asking how to include a variable in text output then:

```
var scoreVar = object.getPoints()
var appName = object.getAppName()
shareToFacebook.setInitialText("I just got \(scoreVar) points in \(appName)")
```

If you're asking something else, then you'll have to be clearer (at least for me!).